# express server cannot accept html form post

Tags: node.js, forms, pug

Every time I try to make a post to my server, for some reason the browser shows me this message: "Cannot POST /" and I am not sure why. I would appreciate some insight.

PUG CODE:

```
doctype html
html
        head
                title This is a test
        body
                form(method= "post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
                        input(type="text" placeholder="insert name here" name="username")
                        input(type="file")
                        button(type= "submit") Please submit
                if reqON_Data
                        each submission in reqON_Data
                                ul
                                        li=submission
```

NODEJS CODE:

```
  1 const express = require('express');
  2 
  3 const app = express();
  4 
  5 if(!app.locals.newData) app.locals.newData = [];
  6 else console.log("app.locals already exists");
  7 
  8 app.set('views', 'views');
  9 app.set('view engine', 'pug');
 10 
 11 app.get("/", (req, res)=>{ 
 12         res.render("test", { "reqON_Data": app.locals.newData});
 13 });
 14 app.post((req, res)=>{
 15         let formData = '';
 16         req.on('data', (d)=>{
 17                 formData += d;
 18         });     
 19         app.locals.newData.push(formData);
 20         res.redirect('/');
 21 });     
 22 
 23 app.listen(8080);
 24 
 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the first argument for your post function it should be:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
   //handle req.body
   res.render("test", data);
})
```